# Switch the Odd One Out #3 (Intermediate)

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

[image: OOO3]

What two figures (one in range a-i and the other in range 1-9) is the odd ones that should be switched to restore both patterns, and why?

*created by myself*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Swap between i) and 3). I now assume that objects can be hidden by other objects, which may or may not be legal. Again, looking at the difference (but this time, ignoring position) we get

This because

> [image]

If we...

> ... now subtract the left from the right, we get a nice distribution of crosses.

Comment: You found the correct answer. I actually didn't intend to create this pattern when comparing the grids against each other but it seems being a logical effect when cancelling the individual patterns out against each other.

Answer (score 0):

> Swap C and 9.
>
>  I based this on the center pieces of each block and matching shapes. Shapes on each block stay the same, just different count, location, and some are overlapping.